# Alternatives of formatting primary harddrive of a laptop

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop

I have an Asus N53SN laptop. One day I decided to format it using recovery partition. I started recovery, left the computer, when I came back 10 minutes later there was a big red error message. After that, whenever I try to turn it on, it is stuck at the ASUS splash screen and the keys to enter BIOS are not responding.

To fix it, I opened it, removed the harddrive, restarted, and I could boot Ubuntu from USB and access the BIOS. Now I know that it is about the harddrive.
Here is the problem: When I plug harddrive back after I changed boot priorities, it automatically sets the harddrive as first and I am stuck at splash screen again.

What I want to learn is this:
Can I plug and format my primary harddrive after laptop has booted from another device?(Like usb)

If it is not possible to do so, how can I fix my harddrive? I also have 2.5" WD external harddrive, is it possible to use its case for one time?

FYI, It was dualbooted (WINDOWS-7 + UBUNTU) before I ran recovery.
It can boot ubuntu from USB or access BIOS when primary harddrive is removed.

Comment: You will be unable to leave the hdd unplugged, boot to the linux drive, and plug the hdd because of the nature of your hardware.  Its very unlikely your hardware supports hot swappable drives.

Comment: Just buy a sata-usb adapter, boot to ubuntu/windows installer, connect the adapter to your harddrive and format it from there

Comment: @Ramhound Is it risky to plug it after ubuntu boots?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo I also have an external 2.5" harddrive, can I use its case for formatting?

Comment: The external harddrive is just normal harddrive plugged into adapter with protective case, so yeah, that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my hardware does not support hot swapping. So there was/is no alternatives of doing such an operation.

Anyway, even if there was, it wouldn't help in my case. Because it turned out that my harddrive was damaged when I tried formatting. I ended up buying a new harddrive.